# Object does not match target type looping through EF properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am trying to get the  values from multiple properties in an entity framework object. There are 11 properties, each with a date assigned to it. I've tried using reflection but I keep getting an error " Object does not match target type"

```
 public void CheckWeekStatus()
    {
     var currentFlexi = from c in FlexiContext.FlexPeriods where c.FlexiCurrentYear == true select c;

     FlexPeriod s = new  FlexPeriod();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = s.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

      foreach (var info in properties)
           {                     
             var o = info.GetValue(currentFlexi,null);                                        
           }
     }
```

FlexPeriod is the type that contains all the properties. I can loop through the properties but obviously I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm trying to access the values. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you can get the `Type` without instantiating an object:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof( FlexPeriod ).GetProperties( ...
```

---

The reason `GetValue` is failing is that `currentFlexi` is a collection of `FlexPeriod` objects ( actually an `IEnumerable<FlexPeriod>` ), not a single instance of `FlexPeriod`.